# adding form element via DOM

Tags: javascript, forms, dom

All the examples if adding a form element to an existing form all use the document.getElementById method of grabbing the element that they want to attach the form element to or they are Jquery methods which I don't use and have no need to use Jquery.

This is the form I have

```
    <form name="formname" action="javascript:return false;" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" onSubmit="processCart(this);">
<table>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td>Number&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td>Price&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td>Quantity&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td>Remove</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="items" value="Item 1"></td>
<td># 1&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td>$<input type="text" name="price" size="12" value="1.00" readonly /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="quantities" value=""/></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
```

The button that Adds an element is called "Add Item" and when clicked it is supposed to add a form element after the existing one.

Any ideas on how to achieve this in Javascript will be appreciated. Clips of code so far

```
function insertFormElements(){

for(i in ele){
    itm = 'item_'+i;
    amt = 'amount_'+i;
    qty = 'quantity_'+i;

    // add a new Inputs
    addElement(itm,"text","");
    addElement(amt,"text","");
    addElement(qty,"text","");
    // add values       
    document.formname[ itm ].value = ele[i].items;
    document.formname[ amt ].value = (ele[i].amount * ele[i].quantity);
    document.formname[ qty ].value = ele[i].quantity;
    }
    return true;
```

}

The function addElement

```
function addElement(){
try{
    var element = document.createElement("input");

    //Assign different attributes to the element.
    element.setAttribute("name", arguments[0]);
    element.setAttribute("type", arguments[1]);
    element.setAttribute("value", arguments[2]);
    document.formname.appendChild(element);
    }catch(e){
        alert( e );
    }
```

}

I have not has an alert and I have not seen any elements get added, so can someone assist with what might be going wrong?

Comment: for(i in ele){ ... what's ele ..?

Comment: You seem to be calling `addElement` with some parameters, yet in your function definition it has none (that's among many things that seem to be wrong).